# How to reference an existing HStack, VStack, and ZStack instance?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I found the new VStack, HStack, and ZStack more confusing to use than the previous UIStackView methods. Is there a way to edit the specific properties, such as color, of an existing Stack programmatically from another function?

For instance,

```
var body: View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Testing.")
        .frame(height: 200, alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

If I had code like this, How can I edit the contents of .frame that belongs to body's VStack? In UIKit, I can do this because a new UIStackView is essentially a variable that can be accessed. This was very useful, because I could create other methods that respond to user input and events to change certain properties of another UIStackView variable. Also do you recommend on learning SwiftUI? Are there certain "freedoms" from UIKit that are deprecated in SwiftUI for the sake of convenience?

Comment: I think you should forget UIKit when learning SwiftUI or at least stop comparing with it when trying to understand how SwiftUI works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a reference to any elements inside `body`, but instead you can update content using Binding/State variables.
For example:

```
@State var update: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Button(action: {
            update.toggle()
        }, label: {
            Text("Testing")
        })
        .frame(height: update ? 200 : 100, alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

In the code above, when you update variable `update`, it forces SwiftUI to refresh the body

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a bit more cumbersome though, since instead of one update function managing properties of multiple stacks, now I have to assign a button or callback function to the stacks themselves.

Comment: well it depends :) in such approach Apples moves to MVVM architecture. Also from my experience, I made all UI by hands, in code, without IB and swiftUI really spends up the process of making UI.

I had doubts about SwiftUI but now I'm really excited using such approach

Comment: "Apples moves to MVVM architecture", as far as I know Apple has never mentioned MVVM when talking about SwiftUI